# crystal reports asp.net do i have to use setdatabaselogon

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report designed using xsd file (dataset with ado.net connection).  Crystal version 14.2.5.2618 and using vs 2017... deployed to .net 4.7.2 framework website.  I have a service (WCF) returning a dataset that is valid and filled.  When I deploy the report to the web server the report prompts for a database login even though it is fine in development.  Here is the code with names changed to protect the innocent.

```
m_myRPT.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/my.rpt"))
m_myRPT.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Portrait
m_myRPT.SetDataSource(m_DS.Tables("dtData")) 'returned from WCF and is fine
CRV_reportviewer.ReportSource = m_MyRPT
CRV_reportviewer.DataBind()
```

Like I said, this works fine in development.  All data is returned properly and the dataset checks out too.
My questions are:

1) Do I HAVE to use SetDatabaseLogon (WCF service supplies data... report should not have access to database and I don't want it to access either)

2) Can I set this up so the dataset table suffices for report data ...

3) Shouldn't the DataSet with a valid table full of data suffice for the report to display... 
So basically...
4) How can I get rid of prompt (preferably without the report having access to the database) ?

Any answer to these questions would be great...  I do not mind changing the report so it does not prompt for data without having to hard code database access credentials anywhere on the web pages...  WCF Service provides data... n-tier application...
I know these are four questions in one but number four is what I really need answered if anyone would be so kind

I used Crystal many times over the years but cannot recall having to give it access to the database...

Best Regards and thank you in advance;

Answer (score 0):

1, You must to ensure, that name of DataTable is the same in CrystalReport, if yes, go next step

2, It s not enough to only Set DataSource to a report, you must pass data to a report :

```
      ds.WriteXml(XmlDataPath)
```

save your dataset as xml, now you can add your generated xml to a Crystal Report, so open Crystal Report, go to Database> Database expert> Create New Connection> ADO.NET(xml) and choose path to generated xml

I faced the same problem, and these steps helped me

Comment: Thanks Peter...  I did change data source location in design of reports and mapped the fields.  I suspect you are dead on as data tables had different names but I mapped fields so it seemed happy...  I will check it out.  Thanks again...  will post results

Comment: No Luck...  Tried a basic report.. from scratch...  I used all the steps in the beginning too but  basic report with couple of fields...  no luck...  Thanks just the same...

Comment: not sure what is the problem... I mean I have a valid dataset from the WCF...  Table Names and all of that check out as far as I can see... Really at a loss as to why these reports are looking for login credentials...

Comment: error was with WCF Peter...  You were correct... access rights...  thanks for your help