# Data Table to Crystal Reports (Missing Fields)

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, ms-access-2016

I tried searching here and other vb forums sadly Icant really find a way to solve my problem.I am trying to use datatable as a datasource for a crystal report. During run time, tried to display the datatable contents on the datagrid which is pretty successful however upon trying to view the report some fields are missing even though I already inserted theses fields in the Crystal report.

To see where I went wrong I tried to do the same thing in another project(for testing purposes only) same codes and everything and it worked fine

What could possibly be the problem here?

Im posting my codes for reference even though I think it is not the problem here

```
    Dim report As New CriticalLevel
    Dim dtbl As New DataTable
    Dim dgv As New DataGridView

    dtbl = convertDGVtoDT(DataGridView7)
    dtbl.TableName = "SampleData"


    report.SetDataSource(dtbl)

    ReportViewer.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
    report.SetParameterValue("User", frmMain.lbl_user.Text)

    ReportViewer.Show()
```

Comment: I tried creating new blank crystal report for this and still the fields are missing

Comment: what fields are shown and what fields are missing? what is the difference between them? i am used to build crystal report from xml data source and it is working.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54434539/10785732

Comment: I already tried that before asking doesn't work for me. anyways I was able to figure it out. thanks